# How to access the data source of a RecyclerView adapter's ViewHolder?

Tags: java, android

The constructor of my RecyclerView's adapter looks like:

```
Context context;
List<ConnectionItem> connections;

public ConnectionsListAdapter(Context context, List connections) {
    this.context = context;
    this.connections = connections;
}
```

After the adapter's declarations, I declare a static ViewHolder class for the RecyclerView, which also handles the onClicks of any buttons:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public Context context;

    public ImageView connectionImage;
    public TextView connectionName;
    public ImageButton startMsg;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView, List<ConnectionItem> connections) {
        super(itemView);
        ...
        startMsg.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ChatActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", connections.get(getAdapterPosition()).getName()); // Error because accessing from static context
        intent.putExtra("id", connections.get(getAdapterPosition()).getUid()); // Error because accessing from static context
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The problem is that `connections` is not accessible from a static context in the ViewHolder static class. What's the best way for my ViewHolder to get information from the RecyclerView adapter? As a workaround, I am passing the data source to the constructor of the ViewHolder and having a new instance variable in the ViewHolder for the data source:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public Context context;
    public List<ConnectionItem> connections;

    public ImageView connectionImage;
    public TextView connectionName;
    public ImageButton startMsg;

public ViewHolder(View itemView, List<ConnectionItem> connections) {
        super(itemView);
        this.connections = connections;
        ...
        startMsg.setOnClickListener(this);
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ChatActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", connections.get(getAdapterPosition()).getName()); // Okay now
        intent.putExtra("id", connections.get(getAdapterPosition()).getUid()); // Okay now
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Does my way at all break the ViewHolder pattern or create any other problems in the future?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your responsibilities/concerns are a little scrambled.

In MVC terms, a `ViewHolder` is really a View. It's just an object that has references to the subviews so that `findViewById()` doesn't have to be called over and over.  But it's still really a view.

However, you have a constructor with Model data as an argument, and that has a bad smell to it.

- The only properties/variables your `ViewHolder` should have are `View`s.
- The only thing your `ViewHolder` constructor should ever be calling is `findViewById()`

You haven't really talked about your adapter much, but you'll notice that you override two methods: `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder`.

Within `onCreateViewHolder` you construct the `ViewHolder` that's applicable to your view type.  That's it.  You may have to inflate different layouts depending on the view type, but you are just dealing with views here. Don't pass any Model data to the `ViewHolder` in the constructor.

Within `onBindViewHolder`, *here* is where you hook up the View to the Model data.

Something that I do frequently is define a `bind()` method for my `ViewHolder` so that it's very clear what Model data is being handed off.  The `bind()` method takes the data and calls `setText` and similar methods to make the views reflect the Model data for that adapter position.

But now we come to the ugly part of `RecyclerView`'s `Adapter` design.  There is no `OnItemClickListener` for the adapter.

Google argues that this is a better design; that events should be handled by the list item view anyway.  I get that.  But the problem is that the event has to meet up with its model data, and it's the adapter that has the model data, not the list item view.

And Google has emphasized that you can't use `final` on values like the position; you need to call `getAdapterPosition()` in order to index the model data.

So now I have gone to a pattern that accommodates all these constraints.

- I define an `interface` for an event listener with a method that takes the position argument.
- I create an instance of the listener in the adapter
- Every time I bind to a `ViewHolder` I pass this listener instance (so the `ViewHolder` does have a reference to the listener, but *not* the adapter)
- On the event handler in the `ViewHolder`, I call `getAdapterPosition()` to get the position of the list item, then I call the listener method with that position
- The adapter gets the listener callback, accesses the correct model data and performs the desired action

So here's an example:  I have a list of items that have been selected, i.e. products in an online shopping cart that have a Remove button with a big X.  Now I have to handle that remove button.

Define the interface:

```
    interface OnItemRemovedListener {

        void itemRemoved(int position);
    }
```

Create an instance of the listener in the adapter

```
    private OnItemRemovedListener mCallback;
```

Set it up in the adapter constructor:

```
    mCallback = new OnItemRemovedListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemRemoved(int position) {
            mItemList.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
```

The `ViewHolder` subclass:

```
public static class ProductItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView mProductName;

    private Button mRemoveButton;

    private OnItemRemovedListener mListener;

    public ProductItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mProductName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        mRemoveButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_button);
    }

    public void bind(Model data, OnItemRemovedListener listener) {

        mProductName.setText(data.getProductName());
        mListener = listener;
        mRemoveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position >= 0) {
                    mListener.itemRemoved(position);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then `onBindViewHolder` override looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.bind(mItemList.get(position), mCallback);
    }
```

Comment: While so old this still holds true today. Also, if you have 10+ view types in a single adapter, many of which require not-so-generic callbacks, this makes Adapter just a mess of code. So, -1 to google.

Comment: This pattern gets a little cleaner with Data Binding, where my ViewHolder gets the binding in the constructor. Then the binding is used in `onBindViewHolder()` (don't forget `executePendingBindings()`!). Once we move to Composables, I imagine this will change yet again.

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter, instead of:

```java
public ConnectionsListAdapter(Context context, List connections) {
    this.context = context;
    this.connections = connections;
}
```

You should have:

```java
public ConnectionsListAdapter(Context context, List<ConnectionItem> connections) {
    this.context = context;
    this.connections = connections;
}
```

Besides, I don't think there's the need to keep your `ViewHolder` class static. So you would access the adapter list data using: `connections.get(getAdapterPosition());`